# Calling method of activity from asynctask

Tags: java, android

I have two classes: `Main - Activity` and `Second - AsyncTask`. I want to fire `mymethod` on button click.

I have tried.

```
public class Second extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    Main main;

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);

    main = new Main(); //Wrong because is an Activity

    Button con = (Button)activity.findViewById(R.id.con);

    con.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            main.mymethod(v);
        }
     });
   }
}
```

But it throws `java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()`.

Comment: Use new to create object of class Main?.

Comment: You don't instantiate `main` object, you just declare it. I don't know if you have a background in C++, but in Java you need to use the operator new to create an instance.

Comment: that may be poor choice of words on my part but i edited it.

Comment: @BhanuKaushik from the given code I assume nowhere, that's why NullPointerException is thrown.

Comment: @ipinak... yes i kno thats y i was pointing it out.

Comment: I didn't put Main main = new Main(); because Main is and Activity...

Comment: Why do you want to launch `Main` activity that way? If you want to launch an activity from an existing one you must specify it in the manifest file first. Have you done that?

Comment: @ipinak I don't want to launch Main activity. I only want to set button method which is in Main class. Manifest is fine.

Comment: @user222 so, main is instatiated somewhare right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your asynctask class should be a private inner class of Main.**
This way you will be able to access everything you want from Main while in Second

The solution where you would pass the main Activity as param to Second would be a bad idea as the activity could be leaked as Second would still have a reference to Main while the system would want to destroy main.

Comment: Looks like it will be the only solution. Thanks

Comment: What about MyActivityClass.this.myMethod() ??

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you never set `main` to an instance so it is `null`.

You need to do something like

```
Main main = new Main();
```

In fact since you are referencing `main` from an inner class you also need to make `main` final so it can be referenced by the inner class:

```
final Main main = new Main();
```

Comment: Just a followup question..Is variable name main allowed ?

Comment: Yes, you can have a Class named Main with a field named "main" with a main method that shadows a new variable named `main`

Comment: Now I get: java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate(). I forgot to say second class extends asynctask.

Comment: This is wrong ! You do not start an Activity like this, you do it this way: context.startActivity(new Intent(context, Main.class)); but this is not the solution for the problem

Comment: @Benoit at the time I gave my answer the question had nothing to do with android programming.  Please see the original version of the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to call your mymethod(View v) then write it within another separate class , better as static method , it will help you to use that method without taking instance of the class. You probably can't use the method of other Activity like you want because as it's a Activity so it must run onCreate before you can use it. Hope it helps.